# Easy merge non-versioned directory with git repository

Tags: git

Non-standard situation, but maybe I'm not the first one to get trapped into it.

Imagine:

1) You have working git directory, up to date
2) You change some files in it 
3) You delete `.git` directory

How to quickly get back to normal work (undo step 3), without checking out to some other directory and moving changed files?

PS: You need those changes from step 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clone repo to other directory and just move `.git` dir from second repo clone back to original one.

Git will detect modifications as unstaged ones.